# Separate Directory for Static Files produced by Nuxt Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a small question

I need a separate directory for the static files produced by Nuxt Js

By Default **Nuxt Js** creates one single directory(dist) for all the files

The reason is I am running **Django Server** as backend and I have to place the static files in a separate directory relative to the template directory

File system

```
--/templates(HTML Files)

--/static(Static Files)
```

Suggest me a Nuxt Config to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the *static* folder, you can create a new folder where you can put your static files. When you run *build*, *Nuxt* simply copies everything that are in the *static* folder into the *dist* folder. So now you'll get a separate static folder within *dist* after a *build* process completes.

Do the same with your *assets* folder.